# sections in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I have a list of object which I want to separate into several sections (2 in this specific case)
Since I'm using adapter based on FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, I don't have a list so I can't simply add headers.
All I could find was a way to add header at the beginning.

I though of 2 directions
 1. order the list by some value and somehow(I have no idea how) add a header for each new value
 2. create separate recyclerviews that will query the list for the specific value

My questions are 
for 1 - is there a way to do what I want?
for 2 - a. does 2 adapters that listening together to the same "list" as 1 adapter will require mode resources?
  b. since I'm using my custom adapter, can I do it as internal implementation? ask the user for some references (activity, layout/s, queries and every other data) and create several recyclerviews(maybe give the user custom class that do it?)

Answer (score 0):

When I implemented a two-dimensional (sectioned) listview in my project, I used ExpandableListView together with BaseExpandableListAdapter, which worked for me.

Have a look here:

[ExpandableListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)
[Android Expandable List View Tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

However, since you want to use a a List based on RecyclerView, you should check out this (I didn't try it so far, but it looks like a good solution for your problem):

[Introducing ExpandableRecyclerView](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/introducing-expandablerecyclerview)

Comment: Thanks, but my main issue is that I don't have a list object. Firebaserecycleradapter is asking just for the query and do all the work of updating the recyclerview by itself

Answer (score 0):

I think, I missunderstood your problem last time. I put some more thought in it, since I'm working on a similar case and I may have a solution for you, at least for your first direction:

First of all, you can order the list by the value of a specified child. You just have to append .orderByChild("child") to your query. For example:
If the objects in your list have a child named "category", you can specify your query like this:

```
mQuery = mRootReference.child("myObjects").orderByChild("category");
```

Then you have to add a header of some sort to the layout of your list items.

Here's how my layout looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/category_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_heading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="category"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="italic|bold"/>
    </FrameLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_firstname"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="firstname"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/category_header"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The FrameLayout works as the header and contains the textView for the heading.

In onBindViewHolder() of your Adapter you need to determine, if the current view needs to show the header. That is the case, if the category of the current item is different from the category of the last item. If that's true, then you setup your header as you like and set its visibility  to View.VISIBLE. If not, you set it to View.GONE.

Here's the code for that:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    PersonData dataItem = getItem(position);
    holder.mTextViewFirstname.setText(dataItem.getFirstname());
    String currentCategory = dataItem.getCategory();

    if (!currentCategory.equals(mLastCategory)) {
        holder.mHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.mTextViewCategory.setText(currentCategory);
        mLastCategory = currentCategory;
    } else {
        holder.mHeader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

mLastCategory is a member of the adapter and holds the category of the last item. It's initialized with null and gets updated, if the category changes.

This is, how it looks like:

[image]

Hope it helps. Please comment, if you have further questions!

Comment: Hi. Thanks.
I will try it later, but I'm mostly wonder.
Does the recyclerview is creating from scratch each change?
What will be the value of mLastCategory if I'm adding new item after the recyclerview is already  initialized?

Comment: I tried now the way you suggested, and as I thought, at first it worked well, but as soon as I change something, like delete the first item of the second section, the new first item doesn't know it now the first(since it's onBindViewHolder not being called as it hadn't changed)